# How to responsibly publish/sign a shell script?

Tags: shell

I want to make a large shell script (actually an awk script) available to use for everyone. I specifically don't want to publish it via host operating system-specific package repositories such as `apt`, `brew`, and similar, as I won't have the resources to maintain multiple package management accounts, and have created the script specifically as a self-contained, standalone script without dependencies. There's a common dislike among experienced Unix and Linux users towards fetching a script using curl and piping it into `sh`, but what else guarantees that my script is not tampered with by third party download sites when it is only commonly known by its name (hopefully, eventually)?